# Text is not selectable on *some* pages after conversion to PDF/A

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I have a XeTeX-generated PDF document which I need to convert to PDF/A-1b. The problem is that after the second call to `gs`, on *some* pages of the final PDF document which have images on them, the text looks really bad and is not selectable in **evince** / **AcrobatPro** any more. This is only true for *some* pages which have images, not *all* pages with images.

In a first call, I embed fonts like this:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPLATFONTS -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dUseCIEColor \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
   -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
   -sOutputFile=PhD-Thesis_Hilboll_v1.1-fontsembedded.pdf \
   -f PhD-Thesis_Hilboll.pdf
```

Then, in a second call to `gs`, I do the PDF/A conversion:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor \
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=PhD-Thesis_Hilboll_v1.1-PDFA.pdf \
   PhD-Thesis_Hilboll_v1.1-fontsembedded.pdf \
   PhD-Thesis_Hilboll-def.ps
```

The PDF/A definition file `PhD-Thesis_Hilboll-def.ps` looks like this:

```
%!
% $Id: PDFA_def.ps 8284 2007-10-10 17:40:38Z giles $
% This is a sample prefix file for creating a PDF/A document.
% Feel free to modify entries marked with "Customize".

% This assumes an ICC profile to reside in the file (ISO Coated sb.icc),
% unless the user modifies the corresponding line below.


systemdict /ProcessColorModel known {
  systemdict /ProcessColorModel get dup /DeviceGray ne exch /DeviceCMYK ne and
} {
  true
} ifelse 
{ (ERROR: ProcessColorModel must be /DeviceGray or DeviceCMYK.)=
  /ProcessColorModel cvx /rangecheck signalerror
} if


% Define entries to the document Info dictionary :

%/ICCProfile (eciRGB_v2.icc) def
/ICCProfile (/usr/share/color/icc/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc) def

[ /Title (Tropospheric nitrogen dioxide from satellite measurements: SCIAMACHY limb/nadir matching and multi-instrument trend analysis) % Customize.
/Author (Andreas Hilboll) % Customize.
%/Subject (Dissertation angefertigt an der Universitaet Bremen) % Customize.
  /DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile :

[/_objdef {icc_PDFA} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
[{icc_PDFA} <</N systemdict /ProcessColorModel get /DeviceGray eq {1} {4} ifelse >> /PUT pdfmark
[{icc_PDFA} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark

% Define the output intent dictionary :

[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFA} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFA} <<
  /Type /OutputIntent             % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /S /GTS_PDFA1                   % Must be so (the standard requires).
  /DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFA}            % Must be so (see above).
  /OutputConditionIdentifier (CGATS TR001)      % Customize
>> /PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFA} ]>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I just realized that the error also happens when I directly do the PDF/A step, without the font embedding first.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the original PDF file contains transparency, which is not permitted in the PDF/A-1 specification. This means that the areas with transparency have to be rendered to images, after which the 'text' is indeed no longer text, its an image. This is speculation of course without being able to see the original PDF file. Sadly there really isn't anything you can do about this (except remove the transparency or produce PDF/A-2 instead). You can perform your 2 steps as one, and I'd suggest you don't do more conversions than absolutely necessary.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, @KenS. I managed to solve all problems by using JPEG instead of PNG. If your comment were an answer, I'd accept it because it helped me not waste any more time on trying to make it work ;)